# Finding the angle between two tangents of a curve

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I just got back from my math test. In the test I encountered the following question:

> A curve is defined by the equation $$x^3+y^3=3xy$$ Find the angle between the tangents at points (-1,1) and (1,2).

After differentiating implicitly, we get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}$

And the equation of the tangents at the above points are:

$y = \frac{x}{3} + \frac{5}{3}$ and $y = 1$

So, I formed a triangle representing one part of the intersection between the two lines, which looks something like this. [image]
Therefore, the angle between them would be $$\arcsin(4/5)$$ Is my approach right or wrong? If its wrong then how would we do this question?

Comment: The points $(-1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ don't satisfy the equation $x^3+y^3=3xy$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I dont have the question with me. I typed it out of memory, I believe there was a constant involved. But I am sure that the equations of the tangents are the same.

Comment: If you change the equation to $x^3+y^3=3xy+3$, it works.

Comment: Oh yes, I think that is the equation.

Comment: You don’t need the equations of the tangents. You only need their slopes, i.e. dy/dx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slope formula: $m = \frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}$

At $P_1 \equiv( -1,1)$, $m_1 = \frac{1-0}{1+1} = 0$

At $P_2\equiv(1,2)$, $m_2 = \frac{2-1}{4-1}=\frac{1}{3}$

> Acute angle between the 2 tangents,

$\phi = \tan^{-1}\big\vert\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\big\vert = \tan^{-1}\big\vert\frac{0-\frac{1}{3}}{1+0} \big\vert = \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @NoLand'sMan Thank you. But kindly accept Michael Rozenberg's answer, as he answered first and I just added how it came to the final step

Answer (score 2):

No, it should be $\arctan\frac{1}{3}.$

By the way, your calculations of slopes are right.

Comment: @Bernard No. It should be that I wrote.

Comment: Sorry. I thought one  of the tangents was a vertical line.